# ionic error with license for [SDK patch applier V4]

Tags: android

I get the following when I do:

`ionic build android`

> Error: /Users/mike/code/ionic/getit/platforms/android/gradlew: Command
>   failed with exit code 1 Error output: FAILURE: Build failed with an
>   exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>
>   > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:   [SDK Patch Applier v4, Google Repository].   Before
>   >     building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and
>   >     complete the installation of the missing components using the Android
>   >     Studio SDK Manager.   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the
>   >     license agreements from one workstation to another, go to
>   >     http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

I run the android SDK manager and do not see this package as an option, and I have SDK Tools, Platform Tools, and Build tools installed as well as the Android SDK.

What am I missing?

Comment: [It looks like its something you're not supposed to see.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=216501)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you update your SDK to the latest version? Because if I just `locate patcher` on my system, I can see the patcher (including version 4) in my sdk directory.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Sorted it out, the answer is to actually install the Google Repository under the andriod SDK manager.  Misleading error message, IMO, though you do accept the license when you install it.

[image]

Comment: Can confirm. I needed to flag *accept license* an normal *install* wasn't enough.

Comment: Confirmed. Darn Licenses and agreements and their lawyers and patents.

Comment: I had to open the SDK manager as administrator before I could install the GoogleRepository, after that everything else I needed installed fine.

Answer (score 24):

Had that issue. You need to install "extra-google-m2repository"

`echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-google-m2repository"`

Comment: Your solution is great as it is always easy and faster to use things from terminal, and it helped me. Anyway could you please tell me How you know the package name is "extra-google-m2repository" for "Google Repository" ?

Comment: This is a command for continuous integration such as Circle CI.

Answer (score 0):

I tried solutions above, still got the same error, until I refreshed my platform sdk with the command:
    android update sdk --no-ui --filter build-tools-25.0.0,android-25,extra-android-m2repository

Note the 25 in the command came from the error message, your number may vary.

This solution came from the idea of the ionic forum:
[Ionic forum thread, solution provided by rafialikhan](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/you-have-not-accepted-the-license-agreements-of-the-following-sdk-component/69570/9)